# How to find out which element the user clicked on the touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find out which element the user clicked on the touch screen and write its id to the console.

I try using the touchstart event, but the result is always undefined.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (event) {
    // The element that was clicked.
    var clickTarget = $(event.targetTouches[0]);

    // Log element id
    console.log(clickTarget.attr('id'));
});
```

I use jQuery in the project so it can be used to solve this issue.

Comment: What about `event.target`?

Comment: Please review the API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`targetTouches` won't return the touched dom. You need to get it from `target` property of it.

```js
$(document).on('touchstart', function (event) {
    // The element that was clicked.
    var clickTarget = $(event.targetTouches[0].target);
});
```